# How to disable inline CSS position attribute

Tags: css, position, overriding

I basically need to disable the inline CSS "position" attribute I am getting from a remotely located code.

I need to go from here,

[image]

To here,
[image]

I tried the following rule but I don't quite know how to disable position attribute like shown in the image.

```
table.fc-border-separate div:nth-child(1)
```

Comment: those div's aren't children of that table

Comment: `table.fc-border-separate + div`

Comment: @KaiQing: Yep, sorry, its a sibling but how do I disable it?

Comment: `table.fc-border-separate + div { position: static !important; }` worked but I am not sure if its the correct way to do it.

Comment: @skip IMHO, using `!important` is kind of a last resort and should rarely be used.

Comment: @Dom: Yep, it just wan't overriding the inline position attribute embedded in some javascript file located remotely. But, is using static the correct way to disable position attribute? I see that its been disabled using that but I do not know if this is how it should be done. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you currently have?

Comment: @Dom: I do not know much HTML, CSS or JavaScript. I somehow try to deal with them using Google and help from people like you sometimes in this great forum. I was basically trying to show sessions on jQuery FullCalender with some server side code in it and on inspection after hours I figured out that the position attribute if disabled it showed me the events. I don't think I would be able to provide jsfiddle for that.

Comment: @Dom: I meant sessions by class schedule.

Comment: @Dom: Provide as in I am not sure if I would be able to create a jsfiddle for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your markup is effected with a plugin or js or some scripts then the absolute position will only be override rather using relative just use static like this

```
table.fc-border-separate + div{position: static !important;}
```

But I'm not sure in your case you could still use relative instead of static.

Comment: Yep, neither `relative` nor `fixed` were working. Only `static` worked.